# showing Animated Gif image in android by using VideoView

Tags: android, imageview, android-videoview

Can we show a animated gif image in android by using `VideoView`? If possible please let me know how it is possible? Else how can I show a gif image in android?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation). This might be what you are looking for.